# The Fixed Points of an Elliptic Element in a Kleinian Group

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry, discrete-geometry, hyperbolic-groups

Let $\Gamma$ be a **Kleinian Group** (a discrete subgroup of $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$) acting on $\mathbb{D}=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$.

Let $\Lambda(\Gamma)$, $\Omega(\Gamma)$ be the **Limit Set** and the **Domain of Discontinuity** of $\Gamma$, respectively. Then we have $\Lambda(\Gamma) \subseteq \partial \mathbb{D}$ and $Int(\mathbb{D}) \subseteq \Omega(\Gamma)$.

Let $T \in \Gamma$ be a **Parabolic** or **Hyperbolic** element, the fixed points of $T$ belong to the limit set $\Lambda(\Gamma)$.

If $S \in \Gamma$ is an **Elliptic** element, its fixed points belong to $\Omega(\Gamma)$ or $Int(\mathbb{D})$?

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $g$ is nontrivial elliptic, preserving the unit disk. Show that the fixed points of $g$ cannot be on the boundary circle of the disk.

Comment: @MoisheKohan that means it belongs to $Int(\mathbb{D})$. There is not chance to be in the domain of discontinuity without being in the interior of the disk.

Comment: No, that's not quite right, this is true only for Fuchsian groups of the 1st kind. Instead, prove that $int(D)$ is contained in the discontinuity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan it is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what?

Comment: See my first hint. It has nothing to do with discrete groups, just understanding of linear-fractional transformations.